# views calls a function on a different database but crystal reports "invalid identifier" error

Tags: oracle, crystal-reports

I've created a view (generic_view) on a database (database1) in schema (general_schema). One of the columns in this view is populated by a function (generic_function) which is stored in the same schema but on a different database (database2). I'm calling the function like:

```
general_schema.generic_function@database2(param1, param2, ... paramN) AS function_column
```

The view and function both compile, and the view generates data for the function_column function. The problem occurs when I try to use this view in crystal reports to generate a report. When I try to add the view I get the error:
*ORA-00904: "general_schema"."generic_function": invalid identifier*

I tried removing all of the content inside the function so that the function just returns 0, but that didn't seem to help.

I'm I calling the function wrong?

Comment: Are you referring to the view in a query, or duplicating the remote call in a query? If you're querying the view you shouldn't see anything about its internal definition. Perhaps your obfuscation is obscuring something important; or you could show your actual call from Crystal Reports, or new code that reproduces the problem if you don't want to show real code.

Comment: I'm just using the Database Expert in Crystal Reports and when I select the database it gives me that error. 
For testing purposes I used a SELECT * FROM generic_view and the column has values, so the function is being called correctly outside of crystal.
It seems like it is a Crystal Reports issue with using a view that calls a function in a different database, as it works outside of crystal.

Comment: Just to clarify the call to the function is inside the views select statement itself.

Comment: Is there a database link set up in `database1` which allows access to `database2`? And then on `database2`, has the user specified in the database link been granted EXECUTE access to `general_schema.generic_function`?

Comment: If the schema that the function is in on database2 is the same as the schema the view is in on database1, would I need a grant? what would that grant look like? Grant execute on general_schema.generic_function to general_schema?

Comment: If it's in a different database then it's a different schema, even if it has the same name. The question is partly how the database link is defined; is that link connecting as the function owner, or as a different user that needs execute permission on that function? (Though if querying the view works outside Crystal, it seems the grants etc. are OK)

Comment: yeah, that's the weird thing; all the grants should be correct and there must be the correct DBLink as the Select works and it calls the function. The column is populated with 0, as the function right now only returns 0 for testing purposes. if I remove the function call the field is populated with NULL, so it must be calling the function in the other database, or how else would it populate the rows with 0?

Comment: In Crystal Reports, are you connected as the same `database1` user you're testing the view with? If not do they have their own database link definition that connects somewhere the function doesn't exist?

Comment: So, as Bob Jarvis described it needed a grant Execute. Our crystal reports setup uses a different schema to select the views so I needed to add the grant execute for that other schema. Thank you for pointing that out. Feel free to put the answer in so I can close this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The schema *names* being the same in different databases doesn't mean they're the same *schema*. You'll need to have a database link set up in `database1` to allow access to `database2`, and then in `database2` you'll need to be sure that the user specified in the database link has been granted EXECUTE access to general_schema.generic_function.

Best of luck.